# PostgreSQL `IS DISTINCT FROM` behaviour with `row` values in triggers

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, liquibase

I have spent some time chasing an unexpected behaviour in a Liquibase (3.6.3) and PostgreSQL (13.9 up to 15.2).

The behaviour is that one of our triggers was preventing updates in DB records when running from a Liquibase session. But the same update query worked fine if I run it manually from `sql`.

I have found a fix, but do not understand why the fix makes any difference and if it's an expected behaviour or a bug in PostgreSQL.

The trigger was attached as `ON BEFORE UPDATE FOR EACH ROW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_record_updated_at_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) THEN
            NEW.record_updated_at = now();
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            RETURN OLD;
        END IF;
    END;
$$
```

This line is important:

```
IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) THEN
```

Apparently PostgreSQL was returning `false` in some cases where the new and old records were different, one of the fields was non-null in `NEW` and `null` in `OLD`.

Rewriting the condition as below changed the behaviour to an expected one:

```
IF NEW IS DISTINCT FROM OLD THEN
```

It did seem the original version was a bit verbose and unnecessary, but both conditions should be work the same, right?

I couldn't find any confirmation of why the behaviour is different, so if anybody has any explanation I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See [Row constructor comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON): *row_constructor IS DISTINCT FROM row_constructor This construct is similar to a <> row comparison, but it does not yield null for null inputs. Instead, any null value is considered unequal to (distinct from) any non-null value, and any two nulls are considered equal (not distinct). Thus the result will either be true or false, never null.*. Are you sure about  "... one of the fields was non-null in NEW and null in OLD"?

Comment: I am, I actually put a `raise exception 'new=% old=%', row(new.*), row(old.*)` to the `else` branch to log the two tuples, and have got this:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: new=(3,"Name","2023-02-23 11:10:19.704236+00") old=(3,"Name",)
    Where: PL/pgSQL function update_record_updated_at_column() line 7 at RAISE [Failed SQL: UPDATE public.properties SET deprecated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 3
```

Comment: 1) Include the information as update to question, not in the comments. 2) You probably want `RAISE NOTICE ...` so you don't stop the trigger with an exception.

Comment: 1) I don't see how this could happen: `select row(3,'Name', '2023-02-23 11:10:19.704236+00') is distinct from row(3,'Name',null); t` 2) In the function I would change `RETURN OLD` to `RETURN NULL` then the update will not happen and you won't get any side effects from other triggers now or in the future.